# Google Sheet: Using drop-down and check-boxes (data type: text & True/False) to filter data

Tags: google-sheets

firstly thanks in advance.

Before posting this, I’ve searched and tried a few guides from several sources.  However, was to no success in constructing formula string.  Filtering data in Google sheet (GS) using Query + other functions is something new to me and I’m still learning.

**Goal:**
Use drop-down and 2 types of check-boxes (data type: text & True/False).  User can select one or more checkboxes to filter data.

**Problem:**
Was not successful to construct formula string to combine drop-down & check-boxes

My GS example was taken from one of the solution which used a simple formula string for check-boxes (data type: True/False) to create filter and hoping I could developed from it.

[My Google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X7f-uh39zLYetjKEw9tf86DUJwjmPj1A48c1KV6fvMo/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you've asked for.  Try the following formula in E6 of your results sheet.  Or see my tab Answer-GK, which I added to your sheet.

```
=iferror(if(or(C5:C13),
            QUERY ('Test string DB'!A3:H12, "Select * WHERE "  &
                           IF(B2="","C <>'' "," C = '"&B2&"'") &
                           IF(C5,   " and D matches '" & B5    & "' ",) &
                           IF(C6,   " and D matches '" & B6    & "' ",) & 
                           IF(C7,   " and D matches '" & B7    & "' ",) &  
                           IF(C8,   " and E matches '" & B8    & "' ",) &  
                           IF(C9,   " and E matches '" & B9    & "' ",) &  
                           IF(C10,  " and E matches '" & B10   & "' ",) &  
                           IF(C11, " and F=TRUE", )            &
                           IF(C12, " and G=TRUE", )            &
                           IF(C13, " and H=TRUE", )),
            QUERY ('Test string DB'!A3:H12,"select * " & if(B2=""," "," where C = '"&B2&"'") ,0)),
  "No results - Reduce your selected criteria")
```

Something to note.  Since some of your data elementss have dedicated columns, and others are shared columns, it limits what you can filter.  For example, you can't find a campsite that has a beach AND a lake, since your data only allows you to have one or the other element.

The same for access - it can't be both walking and 4WD.  So if you check two or more tickboxes, for either Features or Accessible By, you get no results.  You don't have this issue with Ammenities, since you have a separate column (data element) for each of shower, toilet, and plugpoint.  I hope this makes sense,  I assume that you may want to expand your data structure to allow multiple elements, as you have for Amenities.  The formula would need to be modified in that case.

But otherwise I think it is working as you intended.

Let us know of any issues with this.

**UPDATE:**

To perhaps improve the appearance, I modified The "TRUE" values to show as "Y", using hidden columns in J to L, and the following formula in M5.  There are also other ways of doing this.

```
={"Toilet","Shower","Plugpoint";
  arrayformula(if(J6:L,"Y",""))}
```

This adds the three header labels, then looks through columns J,K,L for TRUE values, and returns them as "Y"s.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! really appreciate it! now it's time for me to understand how the formula string works. thank you so much! @kirkg13

Comment: I love the part where you changed 'True' to 'Y' value. It really looks neat. Never thought I could do that.  As for your suggestion to change  'Feature' and 'Accessible by' data structure to be as 'Amenities', agreed, it has to be changed. I'm wondering, if I want to retain the data structure for 'Feature' & 'Accessible by' but allow multiple selections, will the formula string be more 'complicate'? tqvm!

Comment: It all depends on what your filters are meant to do. If you check Shower and Plugin, do you want campgrounds that have both, or campgrounds that have either one.  The same with Features - Lake AND Beach, or Lake OR Beach.  The first is not possible, with your data structure, so the formula could be changed to do an OR comparison for Features and Access.  But if you change your data structure, the formula becomes a little bit simpler.

Comment: thanks! for your clarification.  I have to read and try more to have sense of this.  I plan to include a default 'All' (will change in Data validation) for Ownerhsip drop-down selection so that it always display all before user select Public and so forth.  Which row/part that I should amend the formula, 1.QUERY ('Test string DB'!A3:H12, "Select * WHERE "  & IF(B2="","C <>'' "," C = '"&B2&"'")... [or] 2.  ....& IF(B2=""," "," where C = '"&B2&"'")

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you intended the the Feature and Accessible check boxes to be inclusive and the Amenities to be exclusive. Here is a working example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AqQCKRrhTzJyLWldcpeFAv1o4sLvphv3F52VCgpa4rE/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the formula in E6:

```
=iferror(QUERY(QUERY('Teststring DB'!A3:H12,"select * where C = """&B2&""" AND (D =  """& if(C5 = true,B5,"")&""" OR D = """& if(C6 = true,B6,"")&""" OR D =  """& if(C7 = true,B7,"")&""") OR (E =  """& if(C8 = true,B8,"")&""" OR E = """& if(C9 = true,B9,"")&""" OR E =  """& if(C10 = true,B10,"")&""") ",0),"select * " & if(C11 = true,"where Col6 = true","")&" " & if(C12 = true,if(C11 = true,"AND Col7 = true","where Col7 = true"),"")&" " & if(C13 = true,if(or(C11 = true,C12 = true),"AND Col8 = true","where Col8 = true"),"")&" ",0),QUERY('Teststring DB'!A3:H12))
```

Comment: Great! Its working! Its time for me to understand how the string works. thank you so much @JLMosher